# How to set the Title of a Panorama control from value in a query string?

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I navigate to a view with a Panorama control I would like to set the Title of the Panorama control, the Title value is coming in with a query string from the previous view. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are navigating from other page:
page.xaml,cs:

```
    private void Navigate()
    {
        string name = "Test";
        // Navigate to Panorama page
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/PanoramaPage.xaml?name=" + name, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

PanoramaPage.xaml.cs:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = "";
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("name", out name))
        {
            PageTitle.Text = name;
        }
    }
```